# How to create a function which displays a specific plot depending on user input in R?

Tags: r, function, ggplot2, plot, graph

I have a collection of plots, in this example I'll just be using the following for simplicity:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)

iris <- ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Width, Sepal.Length, colour = Species)) +
  geom_point(size = 3)

mpg <- ggplot(mpg, aes(manufacturer, fill = manufacturer)) + geom_bar() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1))
```

I would like to create a function called `show_plot()` which disaplys the iris plot when `show_plot(plot_name = "iris")` is run and displays the mpg plot when `show_plot(plot_name = "mpg)` is run.

I know that I would start my function with the following:

```r
show_plot <- function(plot_name){

}
```

But I really don't know where to go on from here. Would be great if someone could provide some suggestions :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look into basic if-else statments

```
show_plot <- function(plot_name){
 
  if (plot_name == "iris") {
    
    gg <- ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Width, Sepal.Length, colour = Species)) +
      geom_point(size = 3)
    
  } else if (plot_name == "mpg") {
    
    gg <- ggplot(mpg, aes(manufacturer, fill = manufacturer)) + geom_bar() +
      theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1))
    
  } else {
    
    stop("Please select 'iris' or ' mpg'")
    
  }
  
  return(gg)
  
   
}

show_plot("iris")
```

Comment: Will do, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can get the plot object inside the function with `get` as follows.

```
# 1- Function
show_plot <- function(plot_name){
  return(get(plot_name))
}

# 2- Display the plot
show_plot(plot_name="iris")
```

This would also require that you have created upstream the mpg and iris objects.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)

iris <- ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Width, Sepal.Length, colour = Species)) +
  geom_point(size = 3)

mpg <- ggplot(mpg, aes(manufacturer, fill = manufacturer)) + geom_bar() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1))

show_plot <- function(plot_name) {
  return(get(plot_name))
}

show_plot("mpg")
```

Output for mpg:

[image]